# HTTP Status 404 Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to run my first Java web application in Eclipse and I'm stuck with this error for the last few hours. `http://localhost:8080/` works perfectly well though and the error appears when I attach the application context along with it. The code in the application is very basic with just two simple small files web.xml and index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Simple Web Application</title>
</head>
<body>
Simple Web Application says Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: You need to show the java code if anyone's gonna be able to help you.

Comment: @Gemtastic There is no java code in the program. Just the web.xml with the welcome file configuration and the index.html which is the welcome file. ttp://localhost:8080/ is working fine but ttp://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject is giving me the 404 error.

Comment: You should remove the link from `http://localhost:8080/` because it refers to your computer only. Anyone who would click on it, will get different result (nothing or his own server). What you have in this address is visible only to you.

Comment: @RonC Yes, it does refer to my computer. You haven't answered my question :)

Comment: @Cafecorridor I meant that you should remove the link style from this address as an edit to this question. This address shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: What's the path to the web.xml, and try not copying that ROOT welcome application. You don't need it. You've shown an installed copy of Tomcat--is it the one that's running on port 8080, or the one launched from Eclipse?

Comment: The path to the web.xml is SimpleServletProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml. As for the ROOT welcome application it works fine for me. Only when I add the application context (SimpleServletProject) it gives me the 404 error. And the answer to your last question is - the one launched form Eclipse.

Comment: Can no one help me? :( Just want to add the description of the error - the requested resource is not available.

Comment: There are tons of things that could be happening here. 1 - Your eclipse did not deploy your webapplication to the tomcat; 2 - tomcat doesn't added the `<context>` tag for your project; 3 - some exception may be thrown on your context therefore the tomcat works but not your application; 4 - you have different tomcat configurations on your eclipse and started the wrong one.; 5 - tomcat configuration on eclipse may be pointing to the wrong folder to deploy; 6- lack of CATALINA_HOME enviroment variable. Just for starts. So if you want help I advise you to add more details...

Comment: Go to the tomcat folder and get the logs and see if there is any error messages

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm just following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oX2rw5pAdxw Both times that I tried it from scratch I get the same issue. Also, I have no clue about most of the issues you've talked about. So if you could request specific details..